# critical sections with eventfd and threads

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, pthreads, semaphore

I have bit of a problem which I can't seem to wrap my head around. I am trying to implement a program (for a uni class) which will have n numbers of trains and m numbers of train sations. However, since my number of stations can be less than the trains that are trying to access them, I would like to add a semaphore like mechanism to critical sections (which would be my train stations) but instead of using semaphores, we have to use eventfd in our os class.
Now the problem with my code (so far) seems to be that none of my train threads actually enters a station.

My code would be:

```
    //Task 1 - sync via eventfd 
//train example : 6 trains and just 3 alleys in a critical section -> train station
// threads = trains will stay = sleep in trainstation and print their current state

#include <sys/eventfd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h> //needed for our in-kernel counter
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

//eventfd: read with EFD_SEMAPHORE will decrease counter by 1 and return 1
// int eventfd(unsigned int initval, int flags);
// without just the previous value and resets to zero
// if eventfd counter is at zero when trying to read, it will block until it turns nonzero again (only if fd is not nonblocking!)
// ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count); returns no of bytes if it succeeds
// write adds a number to our 64 bit in-kernel counter
// ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
// fd is readable to select, poll, epoll if the counter is non zero
// select - monitors multiple fds until one or more turn "ready"
// poll - waits for an event on a fd 
// epoll - similar to poll - monitors multiple fds to see if i/o is possible (great for large numbers of fds)
// close - required to release the fd - if all fds get closed = resources will be freed by the kernel
// return value = fd used to refer to the eventfd object; unsuccessful = -1

#define fail(msg) {printf(msg); return EXIT_FAILURE;}

struct stationStruct{
    int stations[3];
    uint64_t sem[3];
};

void threadfunction(void* station){
    int n = 3;
    struct stationStruct *st = station;
    int stillWaiting = 1;
    //reads eventfd to check wether train can enter or not
    while(stillWaiting != 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < n && stillWaiting != 0; i++){
            if(read(st->stations[i], (void*) st->sem[i], sizeof(uint64_t)) > 0){
                stillWaiting = 0;
                printf("\n\ntrain no %ld has arrived at train station no %d \n", (long) pthread_self(), i);
                sleep(1);
                printf("train no %ld is ready for departure\n", (long) pthread_self());
                sleep(2);
                printf("train no %ld has left the train station %d\n", (long) pthread_self(), i);
                //writes in order to release the locked eventfd
                write(st->stations[i], (void*) st->sem[i], sizeof(uint64_t));
                break;
                }
                //else{
                //sleep(3);
                //printf("train %ld has failed to enter station %d\n", (long) pthread_self(), i);
            //}
        }
    }
    pthread_exit((void*)pthread_self);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n = 3;
    int m = 4;
    struct stationStruct station;

    //eventfd creation
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        if((station.stations[i] = eventfd(1, EFD_SEMAPHORE)) > 0){
            printf("Station %d is open\n", i);
        }
        else{
            fail("could not initialize eventfd for station A\n");
        }
    }

    pthread_t threads[m];
    int returnedValues[m];

    printf("Train Stations 0 - %d are open \n", n);
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        sleep(1);
        if(pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, (void*) &threadfunction, (void*)&station) != 0){
            fail("trains did not arrive\n");
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i], (void*) &returnedValues[i]);
        printf("Traind %ld left for good\n", (long) threads[i]);
    }

    printf("Train stations are closing now...\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("sation %d has been closed\n", i);
        close(station.stations[i]);
    }

    printf("Main station has been closed\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: this line: `void threadfunction(void* station){` is not a valid signature for a thread function.  It should be: `void * threadfunction(void* station){`  Note the `*`.

Comment: this line: `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` must be at the top of the file so it is 'visible' in all the header files.

Comment: `pthread_self()` is a function, so it must have the trailing `()`

Comment: when the `argc` and `argv` parameters of the function: `main()` are not gooing to be used, then the signature for `main()` should be: `int main( void )`

Comment: when printing an error message (which should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`,  the function: `printf()` will not do the job (and it does not output the error message from the OS.)   strongly suggest using `perror()` instead.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) consistently indent the code

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings,  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`   I also use: `-Wconversions -std=gnu99` )   Then fix all the warning and error messages output by the compiler

Comment: it is usually not a good practice to write macros that implement functions.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. (magic numbers are numbers with no basis) the 'magic' numbers are: 3, 4.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the thread function seems to exit as soon as the train enters any station, so each train only visits a single station, not all the stations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a small pointer error?

```
if(read(st->stations[i], (void*) st->sem[i], sizeof(uint64_t)) > 0){
```

...

```
write(st->stations[i], (void*) st->sem[i], sizeof(uint64_t));
```

Should be

```
if(read(st->stations[i], &st->sem[i], sizeof(uint64_t)) > 0){
```

...

```
write(st->stations[i], &st->sem[i], sizeof(uint64_t));
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works perfectly now! (i spent about 9 hours trying to figure out what was wrong - I am so happy that it works :)